# Will editing an MP3 harm the quality?

Tags: mp3, flac, audacity, lossless

I recently recorded something in [MP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) — I should have done [FLAC](https://xiph.org/flac/), but it’s way too late — and I wanted to edit those soundtracks from 5 minutes to about 2 minutes each. I edit in [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). Will loading it, removing about half the track, and exporting again to MP3 harm the quality?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/409238/how-do-i-split-an-mp3-file-without-re-encoding-it

Comment: always keep your recordings in uncompressed or lossless formats: e.g. wav, flac, etc. and encode for publishing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. MP3 is lossy so if you re-encode the new file to MP3 with Audacity/LAME, you *will* lose quality. But if you output the cropped file using a lossless codec such as FLAC, the quality should be no worse than the imported MP3.

Some other tools allow you to crop MP3 tracks without re-encoding, such as [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) and [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html). See [How do I split an MP3 file without re-encoding it?](https://superuser.com/questions/409238/how-do-i-split-an-mp3-file-without-re-encoding-it)

Comment: Is there a Linux alternative?

Comment: Alternative to what? mp3splt and mp3DirectCut from the linked question are both available for multiple platforms, including Linux and Windows--as is Audacity.

Comment: Looking at the picture I thought it was a windows program but now I see its an old LXDE theme or something from knoppix. Thanks

Comment: @NickBailuc glad to help!