# Is it possible to cut mp3 file with Audacity without losing any quality (recording, etc.)?

Tags: audio, mp3, audacity, cut

I want to cut mp3 files with Audacity without losing any quality (recording, etc.). I am aware of [other options](https://superuser.com/questions/409238/how-do-i-split-an-mp3-file-without-re-encoding-it) but I want to do it with Audacity if possible because I use it for other things too.

Comment: You will have to export it as `.mp3` sooner or later so it will always lose quality, unlike when using mp3DirectCut.

Comment: Unless you use a lossless format for the edited files (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Audio)), you will inevitably lose some quality, regardless of your editing software, since MP3 is a lossy format: an editor needs to decompress for editing and any lossy recompression will lose quality. When it has been important, I have managed to trim content from the start and end of compressed files with a binary editor, and restore the metadata afterwards, but it's a lot of hard work to find the cut points, and is realistic only for these most basic edits.